# Searchview issues in fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I am using a searchview in fragment for search in listview. I am able to perform search, but I am facing two issues.

1) When there are no matching users in the list, it gives the last searched result.

**What I want:**

I want to display a message saying "No search results"

**What I have tried:**

I have taken a textview in the same xml in which listview is there andin java file after setting the adapter value, I am using setEmptyView method, still I am not getting the desired results.

**XML code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.rider.project.Fragments.UsersListFragment">


<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="No search results"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.program_list, users );
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
```

**I have tried the various solutions, still I am unable to find the result.**

2) I have a userlist in one fragment `UserListsFragment.java` in which my searchview is there and then if we search some user the lists displays the search results. On clicking on any of the users name a chat screen opens `ChatFragment.java`. Now when I press back button from the chat screen, only those searched users are available in the list and the search menu gets closed as well.

**What I want:**

On clicking back button, I want the complete list to be displayed not only the previously searched users.

**What I have done**

**UserListsFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_userlist,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Log.i(TAG,newText);
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}

private void logoutUser(){
    Intent I = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(I);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuSearch :
            return true;

        case R.id.menuLogout :
            logoutUser();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

            if (results.values != null) {
                clear();
                addAll((List<UserData>) results.values);
                arrayList = (List<UserData>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
            List<UserData> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<UserData>();

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<UserData>(arrayList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
            }

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                // set the Original result to return
                results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                results.values = mOriginalValues;
            } else {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                    String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).getName();
                    if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                        FilteredArrList.add(mOriginalValues.get(i));
                        results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                        results.values = FilteredArrList;
                    }
                }
                // set the Filtered result to return

            }

            return results;
        }

    };
    return filter;
}
}
```

Comment: you need some custom adapter like: `class Adapter extends` [MatchableArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)`<UserData> { ...` and override its `onBind` and `matches` methods

Comment: I am already extending
`public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserData> implements Filterable`

Comment: So dont extend ArrayAdapter,  extend MatchableArrayAdapter  instead

Comment: It gives me an error 'Cannot resolve symbol MatchableArrayAdapter

Comment: you have a link in my first comment

Comment: i think if you start another activity named searchactivity, your problem would be solved without any complication and hard work.

Comment: For issue 1, I think that when there is nothing matched, result is null and you have to do something in publishResults(). Hope it help!

Comment: @I_A_Mok Yeah, I figured this thing out. But, do you have some clue how can I do that because I have to print some message in the listview which I am accessing in UserListFragment.java

Comment: Not sure if this is a good idea but I think the simplest way is to put the adapter as inner class of the fragment, so you can easily access anything inside the fragment. Otherwise you need to google for how to update/access fragment from adapter.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you search something but don't find anything then, set empty textview to `"No search results"` and set it to `listView` again like:

```
tv.setText("No search results");
listView.setEmptyView(tv);
```